# CCSprite with image file and sound file

Tags: objective-c, image, audio, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I see how to add a image file to a CCSprite but how can I also add a audio file?

Is the an attribute I can store a map or dictionary?

FYI I'm on a mobile device posting this so code is not an option right now, will try to update my question

UPDATE:

What I'm trying to do is associate an audio file with each CCSprite and on touch drag play the audio file. 
Each CCSprite will play a different audio file. 
I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to either attach or associate the audio file with the CCSprite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is the approach I'd prefer, depending on whether you are playing a "background music" sound or an "effect" sound:

**If you are playing an `MP3` sound, ie background music:**

1) Add a parameter to the sprite constructor to assign a sound file:

```
[MySpriteClass spriteWithSound:@"mySound.mp3"];
```

2) Simply use:

```
// on touchDragged:
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:self.sound];

// on touchEnded: touchCancelled:
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopBackgroundMusic];
```

**NOTE:** This approach is simple because you can only play one BGM at any given time.

---

**If you are playing an uncompressed sound, ie effect:**

1) Add a parameter to the sprite constructor to assign a sound file:

```
[MySpriteClass spriteWithSound:@"mySound.caf"];
```

2) Play the effect on `touchDragged:` while storing the return value:

```
// on touchDragged:
soundID = [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:self.sound];
```

3) Stop the effect on `touchEnded:` using the `soundID`:

```
// on touchEnded: cancelled:
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopEffect:soundID];
```

**NOTE:** This approach is better as it allows you to play more sounds at a time.

---

**Final Remarks:**

If you have subclasses of each different sprite (ie, `FishSprite`, `DogSprite`, ... etc), such that **ALL** instance of any given class have the same sound, it would be better to add static method to return the sound name for that class:

```
// somewhere in DogSprite.m
+ (NSString *)soundName {
    return @"bark.caf";
}
```

And for the sake of completeness, add a superclass that implements the `touchDragged:`, `touchEnded:`, so you don't have redundant code:

```
// on touchDragged:
soundID = [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:[[self class] soundName]];

// on touchEnded: cancelled:
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopEffect:soundID];
```

Comment: this is what I need, will try this out +1 for the post. Thanks!

Comment: @PhillPafford I hope it works :) .. btw, I just realized that you would probably use `sprite.soundName` not `self.soundName`, since the touch handler is usually not the sprite itself, but it can be that way.

Answer (score 1):

In **Cocos2D** you can add the `audio file` like this:-

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"soundeffect.mp3"];
```

Once the `sprite` is added, you can use this audio file.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
```

And then Simply

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"XYZ.mp3"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I didn't ask it correctly, what I'm trying to do is associate an audio file with each CCSprite and on touch drag play the audio file. Each CCSprite will play a different audio file. I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to either attach or associate the audio file with the CCSprite

Comment: set all audio name in one array. and set tag's to each sprite. on the tag base get the name of you sound file from array then you can play audio on sprite.

Answer (score 0):

If you can subclass it, then do that and add a property for an audio file. As far as I can tell, no, you can't add any extraneous information without subclassing. But I don't use cocos2d, so take that with a grain of salt.